# Creating Facebook story in Android, getting can't generate preview error

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook story in my android app.  Currently the app tries to open Facebook for a moment then stops and heads back to the app ui.  My stack logs a Facebook error "can't generate preview".

Here's the relevant code:

```
OpenGraphObject whiskeyCheckin = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("whiskeynation:whiskey");
    whiskeyCheckin.setProperty("type", "whiskeynation:whiskey");
    whiskeyCheckin.setProperty("title", whiskeyName);
    whiskeyCheckin.setProperty("description", whiskeyCheckinCaption + whiseyCheckinDescription);
OpenGraphAction action = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("whiskeynation:rate_a_whiskey");
    action.setProperty("whiskey", whiskey);
    action.setType("whiskeynation:rate_a_whiskey");
FacebookDialog graphBuilder = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "whiskey")
            .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(graphBuilder.present());
```

For the story (as set in the FB dashboard) "whiskeynation" is the namespace, "rate_a_whiskey" is the name story/action name, and "whiskey" is the object name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not using your OpenGraphObject whiskeyCheckin.

From the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder/

The last parameter of the OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder constructor, previewPropertyName, must reference a property that contains the Open Graph Object:

*previewPropertyName: The name of a property on the Open Graph action that contains the Open Graph object which will be displayed as a preview to the user*

This might be what you want:

Replace this:

```
action.setProperty("whiskey", whiskey);
```

...with this, which references your OpenGraphObject:

```
action.setProperty("whiskey", whiskeyCheckin);
```

Comment: That was it.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: No prob, glad I could help!